# Excluding the partition field from select queries in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hiveql

Suppose I have a table definition as follows in Hive(the actual table has around 65 columns):

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE S.TEST (
    COL1 STRING,
    COL2 STRING
)
PARTITIONED BY (extract_date STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\007'
LOCATION 'xxx';
```

Once the table is created, when I run `hive -e "describe s.test"`, I see `extract_date` as being one of the columns on the table. Doing a `select * from s.test` also returns `extract_date` column values. Is it possible to exclude this *virtual*(?) column when running select queries in Hive.

Comment: why can't you run select col1,col2 from test

Comment: Like I said,  I have 450 tables in hdfs and some have close to 65 column.

Comment: Does all of your query will be used as select * from <table>

Comment: Yes, we are doing data validation between DB2 and Hadoop(Db2 is the source data base and we export and then import data to Hadoop). So, it would be a lot easier for us to just run `select * from.. ` on both system and just diff the data files

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change this property

```
 set hive.support.quoted.identifiers=none;
```

and run the query as

```
SELECT `(extract_date)?+.+` FROM <table_name>;
```

I tested it working fine.

Comment: though, I cannot do this: `hive -e "set hive.support.quoted.identifiers=none; select \`(extract_date)?+.+\` from test"`. I get error: "cannot recognize input near 'from'..." This works only when both the commands are in a file and I do: `hive -f <hive.sql>`